# How do i know how many amps to send to my subpanel?

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I am building a 24'x15' woodworking shop inside a larger pole barn. I want to put a subpanel in the shop fed by the buildings main panel but how do i estimate the size of the breaker to use in the main panel to send enough power to feed the shop? Is there a general guild line for woodshop power usage?

Comment: I think you are asking the question backward. Figure out what maximum amperage your shop might need for a reasonable combination of machines running at once plus lighting, add some to allow for possible other needs later,and size the sub-panel,  and the wires to it and the breaker that feeds it from the main panel, appropriately.

Comment: that sounds reasonable.  Does anyone know of a good estimated amp usage table for various power tools?

Comment: I'd just start looking at catalogs. Motor horsepower can be translated to Watts (1 British horsepower =

745.7 watts
) and if you divide power in Watts by voltage you get the amperage. Figure out what each tool probably needs, then look at which you might actually run simultaneously (in a one-person shop that might be something like one major tool plus dust collection --  you don't often leave tools running unattended),  and so on.

Comment: may need stereo, mini fridge etc. (: Thanks for the info.

Comment: @woodmanbyday - many gas powered electric generators have listings of common tools & their power requirements.  I suggest starting there. Here is one url that can help too:  https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/buyers-guides_wattage-calculator

Answer (score 1):

You haven't been very specific about what type of equipment you'll have in the shop, so it's impossible to give an accurate estimate.

I generally recommend 60-100 amperes, depending on what type of equipment and how much time you'll be spending on the shop.

Comment: i am in the process of upgrading to contractors table saw and adding a planer. other than those i have radial arm, 6" jointer, miter saw, scroll saw, band saw, drill press and router table. no dust collection yet, usug shop vac. want to put in a couple 220 outlets for table saw and future expansion. thats what i can think of at the moment.

Comment: @woodmanbyday what about HVAC (heating, cooling)?

Answer (score 0):

Go shopping or "just browsing" & write down the specs of your tools of choice. How many volts & how many amps. For tools that you have this is quite easy. If you prefer to go by Watts to double check your Amp add-up wire size & handling capacity, the formula is just Volts X's Amps = Watts.

Then, you want to go even higher or more for future items. Like, dust collection system, lighting, central vacuum, heating, cooling, vacuum press, painting & staining room ventilation, a showroom, studio lighting, computer, microwave, refrigerator, TV, oven, beer meister for when I come over & play.

Comment: may need to double the size. there will be no room for the recliners. thanks

Comment: I'm fine with a loft, don't strain yourself :)